# oak version upgrade in aem

Tags: versioning, aem, jackrabbit-oak

I am using AEM 6.1, and upgrading my AEM instance with SP2. I have installed CFP 3 and SP2 in AEM 6.1. earlier my oak version is showing 1.2.7 but after installation of SP2 and CFP ; oak version got downgraded to 1.2.18. but blog[1](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/release-notes--aem-6-1-cumulative-fix-pack-.html) say: *If your instance is running a higher version of Oak compared to the Oak version of the CFP package, the latter will not impact your current Oak version.*

Could you please let us know is there any way to upgrade oak version in my AEM instance? if not does this oak going to impact any functionality in our existing instance?

1. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/release-notes--aem-6-1-cumulative-fix-pack-.html

Thank you! - **Rashid**

Comment: 1.2.18 is higher that 1.2.7 so it's not a downgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AEM products, patches, hotfixes, service packs and CFP, all follow the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) guidelines. A newer package will always have a higher version number.

Package installer, will never downgrade a version unless you delete the older version and install a lower version of the package. For OAK, this is not possible as you cannot delete the OAK packages without destroying your instance.

AEM 6.1 shipped with OAK 1.2.7
[AEM 6.1 SP2](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/release-notes-sp2.html) ships with OAK 1.2.16
[AEM 6.1 SP2 CFP3](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/release-notes--aem-6-1-cumulative-fix-pack-.html) ships with OAK 1.2.18

Based on your installation order, SP2 CFP 3 will always upgrade oak to 1.2.18 if a lower version is found from base SP2 or earlier CFP's.

If you want to upgrade just the OAK version, then you can get the latest AEM 6.1 compatible OAK patch from [official package share site mentioned here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/aem61-available-hotfixes.html#COREHOTFIXESACROSSAEMPRODUCTSAEMPLATFORM)

At the time of writing, the highest compatible OAK version for AEM 6.1 is 1.2.24. This can be installed regardless of which SP or CFP you have and will work without any issues.

You can always verify the version of your OAK on the instance by going to [server]:[port]/system/console/bundles and checking the version of 'Oak Core' bundle.

Hope this helps.